# I need to subtract a set amount from a progress bar and keep getting an out of range message

Tags: c#

I have a checkbox that increments a progress bar by 20 percent when checked and decrements by 20 percent when unchecked (or at least that is what I want it to do).  It works to increment, but when I uncheck the box, VS screams at me and tells me the "Value of '-20' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'." Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
private void chkAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkAlpha.Checked == true)
    {
        pbWaitMessage.Value = (intPBValue + intIncrementValue);
    }
    if (chkAlpha.Checked == false)
    {
        pbWaitMessage.Value = (intPBValue - intIncrementValue);
    }
}
```

I have previously declared the following variables:

```
int intPBValue = 0;
int intIncrementValue = 20;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a range check. For eg. Inc by 20 only when the value is less than 100 and decrement by 20 only when the value is greater than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't ever setting the value of intPBValue.

You could use:

```
if (chkAlpha.Checked == true)
{
    pbWaitMessage.Value += intIncrementValue;
}
if (chkAlpha.Checked == false)
{
    pbWaitMessage.Value -= intIncrementValue;
}
```

[Edit]

Or, to refactor as per comment :)

```
if (chkAlpha.Checked)
{
    pbWaitMessage.Value += intIncrementValue;
}
else
{
    pbWaitMessage.Value -= intIncrementValue;
}
```

Comment: If a boolean is not true it will be false ;) You see what I mean?

Comment: Value is an int.  I just replicated the structure in the original question rather than refactoring it.  That wasn't where the problem lies with the code.

Comment: Fair enough, but educating the OP about that won't hurt you is what I feel.

Comment: Oops, that will teach me to edit in a hurry, missed the redundant `== true` :)

Comment: Ah! I didn't see += and -= . Looking at the error message I just assumed boundary condition as the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify `intPBValue` and make sure values don't go out of bounds...

```
private void chkAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkAlpha.Checked)
    {
        intPBValue += intIncrementValue;
    }
    else
    {
        intPBValue -= intIncrementValue;
    }

    if (intPBValue < 0)
    {
        intPBValue = 0;
    }
    else if (intPBValue > 100) // assuming 100 is the max
    {
        intPBValue = 100; 
    }

    pbWaitMessage.Value = intPBValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
int intIncrementValue = 20;


private void chkAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (chkAlpha.Checked)
   {
     if(pbWaitMessage.Value + intIncrementValue <= pbWaitMessage.Maximum)
        pbWaitMessage.Value = pbWaitMessage.Value + intIncrementValue ;
   }
   else
   {
     if(pbWaitMessage.Value - intIncrementValue >= pbWaitMessage.Minimum)
        pbWaitMessage.Value = pbWaitMessage.Value - intIncrementValue ;
   }
}
```